# Unable to turn on "Snapshot" in Android Studio AVD Manager & save it

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Android Studio 2.1.3 on Windows 10 64 bit.

I go to `Tools->Android->AVD Manager`.
It shows me an error "Android Virtual Device" failed to load - click <kbd>Details</kbd> to see the error.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg4SC.png]

When I click <kbd>Details</kbd>, it does not show any error.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCree.png]

When I click on <kbd>Edit</kbd> & try to turn of "Host GPU" & turn on "Snapshot" option, the <kbd>OK</kbd> button remains grayed out - so I cannot save the Snapshot Option.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fswC.png]

The emulator itself runs fine - however, how do I turn on the Snapshot option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to your SDK manager and making sure everything is updated. Your options are slightly different and I believe it's because you are using an older version.

They now have the Emulator Accelerator. You can also select to run off of your hardware and choose the number of Cores from your CPU to assign to the virtual device. [image: Check this out]

Comment: `you are using an older version` - I installed on thursday, I think :-(.  Anyway, where do I see the Emulator Accelerator - I want to run it using Hardware rather than Software.

Comment: Found the Option for Hardware Graphics - so ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

accroding to this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/V88yP.jpg you have not set **skin** ..so please choose **skin** option then you will be able to see **ok** button

Comment: Tried after setting a skin - the OK button remains greyed out.